# found/not-found indication with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I routinely use following primitive elements in some internal tables.

X const* find(Key const& key);

If found return pointer to found element if not found return null.

I would like to do something similar with shared_ptr instead of naked pointer.

Comment: Just a word of advice: You might want to return a weak_ptr instead, but use shared_ptr internally within the data structure.

Comment: Or you could use unique_ptr internally and return a reference if the container is expected to have sole ownership of its contents.

Comment: @Rob Jinman. I expect that returned reference may be held in some other object hence my interest in shared_ptr. I expect that internal table will be shared_ptr based, so passing it out as the result of the search will be the cheapest option. IMHO user of this interface should decide between using weak_ptr or shared_ptr for its internal purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem, it works the same way more or less.  `shared_ptr` has a default constructor which makes a "null" pointer, and it also has an operator which lets you evaluate the `shared_ptr` in a boolean context like an `if` conndition.  So when you have nothing to return, just say:

```
return shared_ptr<X>();
```

And to test it:

```
if (shared_ptr<X> ptr = myFunc()) {
  // do something with *ptr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're insisting on returning shared_ptr? shared_ptr are tools for managing memory. You can use these inside your function. However it won't make any difference to caller of your function whether you are returning a shared_ptr, reference/raw-pointer.( In an asynchronous context, there are many pitfalls ).

Also, shared_ptr's are based on reference counting mechanism i.e they are deleted only when it is no longer referenced by anyone. So, if you are returning it you have to make sure you are not storing it permanently which would never enable it's reference count to reach 0.